# How to create segue using multiple buttons to a webView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, segue

I have two viewcontroller. I am trying to load multiple url in one webview using buttons. My first viewcontroller contains buttons and second viewcontroller contains a uiwebview. I have connected two buttons to the webview by control+click+dragging.Here is my code. It doesn't work. What's the problem?

first vc:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var link1: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var link2: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func link1(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("link1", sender: sender)
    }

    @IBAction func link2(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("link2", sender: sender)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        let websiteController = segue.destinationViewController as webViewController
        if segue.identifier == "link1" {
            websiteController.urlWebsite = "www.google.com"
        } else if segue.identifier == "link2" {
            websiteController.urlWebsite = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
        }

    }



}
```

second vc:

```
import UIKit

class webViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    var urlWebsite: String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let myURLString = urlWebsite
        let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString!)
        let myURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: myURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(myURLRequest)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: What does not work? The button events or the segue? Do you reach the `prepareForSegue`function?

Comment: When i click on button "link1" it is crashing and showing message - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<Multi_button_webView.ViewController: 0x7ff2935832b0>) has no segue with identifier 'link1''. Same in "link2".

Comment: You can create segue like these screen shot image urls: http://postimg.org/image/7pvin00l1/     
http://postimg.org/image/qit25ylqp/

Comment: This time not crashing but after clicking button no response in second vc

Comment: What is your xCode version?

Answer (score 0):

I think, your issue is in this line of code :

```
if segue.identifier == "link1" {
    websiteController.urlWebsite = "www.google.com"
}
```

you need to add prefix **http://** in url . so the your code is like below

```
if segue.identifier == "link1" {
    websiteController.urlWebsite = "http://www.google.com"
}
```

Comment: This is also an issue in his code.. so why pressed down in my answer.. can you explain it..